Making SVG zoomable using transforms
I am trying to make a part of SVG draggable and zoomable using mouse but I am failing. The dragging works but zoom doesn't work. I basically stole most of the code from here.
var makeDraggable = (function() {
    function makeDraggable(svg, element) {
        var selected = false;
        var transform, offset;
        var container = svg.parentElement;

        // Make sure the first transform on the element is a translate transform
        var transforms = element.transform.baseVal;
        if (transforms.length === 0 || transforms.getItem(0).type !== SVGTransform.SVG_TRANSFORM_TRANSLATE) {
            // Create a transform that translates by (0, 0)
            var translate = svg.createSVGTransform();
            translate.setTranslate(0, 0);
            element.transform.baseVal.insertItemBefore(translate, 0);
        }

        svg.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrag);
        svg.addEventListener('mousemove', drag);
        svg.addEventListener('mouseup', endDrag);
        svg.addEventListener('wheel', zoom); // Attach zoom function to mouse scroll event

        function getMousePosition(evt) {
            var CTM = svg.getScreenCTM();
            if (evt.touches) { evt = evt.touches[0]; }
            return {
                x: (evt.clientX - CTM.e) / CTM.a,
                y: (evt.clientY - CTM.f) / CTM.d
            };
        }

        function startDrag(evt) {
            selected = element;
            transform = transforms.getItem(0);

            // Get initial translation
            offset = getMousePosition(evt);
            offset.x -= transform.matrix.e;
            offset.y -= transform.matrix.f;
        }

        function drag(evt) {
            if (selected) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                var coord = getMousePosition(evt);
                transform.setTranslate(coord.x - offset.x, coord.y - offset.y);
            }
        }

        function endDrag(evt) {
            selected = false;
        }

        function zoom(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();

            // Get the current scale
            var transform = transforms.getItem(0);
            var scale = transform.matrix.a;

            // Calculate the new scale based on mouse wheel direction
            var scaleStep = evt.deltaY > 0 ? 0.8 : 1.25;
            var newScale = scale * scaleStep;

            // Limit the scale to a minimum of 0.1 and a maximum of 10
            newScale = Math.max(0.1, Math.min(newScale, 10));

            // Apply the new scale to the element
            transform.setScale(newScale, newScale);

            // Adjust the translation to keep the same point under the mouse
            var mousePosition = getMousePosition(evt);
            var scaleFactor = newScale / scale;
            var deltaX = mousePosition.x * (1 - scaleFactor);
            var deltaY = mousePosition.y * (1 - scaleFactor);

            // Update the translation
            transform.setTranslate(transform.matrix.e + deltaX, transform.matrix.f + deltaY);
        }
    }

    return makeDraggable;
})();

jsfiddle

Zooming an SVG is doable but with a catch...
The onwheel event can only be added to document.body or window but not directly to the SVG.
<!DOCTYPE html><head></head><body>

<script>

var Z=1;

window.onwheel=function(e){if(e.deltaY>0){Z-=0.1;} else if(e.deltaY<0){Z+=0.1;} svg1.style.zoom=Z;};

</script>

<br>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg1" style="width:100px; height:100px;"><path d="M1 7.5h30V1.9H1v5.6zm0 22.6h30v-5.6H1v5.6zm0-11.3h30v-5.6H1v5.6z"/></svg>

<br>This text and the image below should remain the same size...<br><br>

<img id="svg2" src="file:///C:/Users/HP_Desktop/Desktop/svgtest.svg" height="100" width="100" border="0">

</body></html>

Notes:
Tested OK in Chromium.
The zoom works on both the inline and the image tag SVG when you set its ID to zoom.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
